# Would it be a benefit to install winglets on a Hawker 400XP?

Tags: aircraft-performance, equipment, winglets

Would it be a benefit to install winglets on a [Hawker 400XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_400)? If so how much would the performance be increased?

Comment: If the plane is properly designed, probably none or insignificant. Essentially a winglet is equivalent to extending the wing a bit. Now for given speed, altitude and weight, there is some optimal wing span and if the aircraft already has it, extending it does not help. That's why winglets are mostly seen on later generations of transport aircraft—they are usually heavier than the earlier versions, so they should have bigger wings too, but redesigning the wings is a lot of work, so winglets are used as slightly worse, but much cheaper alternative. Hawker 400 XP is not that case.

Comment: If that is true, what is the justification for the A320 with sharklets?

Comment: @Koyovis there is a restriction on wingspan for things like airport gates.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
Hawker 400XP with winglets.

> HAWKER WINGLET BENEFITS
>
> - 3-4% range increase and precise handling characteristics
> - 9% reduction in time to climb
> - Fast cruise speeds at same fuel flows
> - Increases resale value
>
> — [txtav.com](http://txtav.com/en/service/hawker-400xp-winglets)

---

Related: [Is a winglet better than an equal span extension?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/is-a-winglet-better-than-an-equal-span-extension)

Comment: Not sure where that image came from (providing a source would be awesome), but it looks like the photographer was standing about 1 step to the left of the center line.That would probably annoy those with a touch of OCD.

Comment: @FreeMan - lol, same source as the quoted spex ;)