# What were the L/D ratio of the A-90 Orlyonok at its different operational atlitudes?

Tags: ground-effect, ekranoplan

The [A-90 Orlyonok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-90_Orlyonok) was designed to operate in ground effect ([altitude significantly lower than its wingspan](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43050/3394)). If I understand correctly, when in ground effect, the L/D ratio is better due to induced drag being lower. Thus, I imagine the L/D ratio of the A-90 is high when cruising near at low altitude, but I failed to find any figure *. Moreover, according to Wikipedia, this aircraft have a ceiling of 3000m (not really in ground effect).

I'm interested in the performance differences between flying at ground effect altitude and at almost 10000ft AGL.

What were the L/D ratio of the A-90 Orlyonok at its different operating altitudes (when in ground effect, at its ceiling, and at any other altitude it would spend time flying at)?

---

<sub>* I only find [a paper](https://www.slideshare.net/StephanAubin/eages-proceedings-edwin-van-opstal) that states [GEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-effect_vehicle) in general have a L/D ratio of 23 without saying if it applies to the A-90 nor at what altitude this L/D ratio is found</sub>

Comment: As I read it, the 23:1 L/D value is for the Lippisch X-112. Of course there cannot be just one value, especially without giving a height at which this value applies.