# Is the Embraer E190-E2 equipped with raked wingtips?

Tags: boeing-777, winglets, wing-tip-vortex, embraer-e-jet

It looks like [the Embraer E190-E2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_E-Jet_E2_family#E190-E2) has a raked wingtip, but isn't a raked wingtip only efficient for long-haul aircraft like the Boeing 77W?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a winglet better than an equal span extension?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/is-a-winglet-better-than-an-equal-span-extension)

Comment: Why would an aerodynamic device only be useful for long-haul aircraft?

Comment: @egid I believe OP is referring to the aerodynamics advantage vs. weight disadvantage, which is a real concern on larger aircraft with raked wingtips and other winglet-like devices (without saying that this is necessarily a concern on a similar scale with smaller aircraft with smaller, lighter components).