# Why are there different types of winglets?

Tags: aircraft-design, drag, winglets

If all winglets serve the same purpose (to reduce vortex drag), why do different aircraft have different winglets? This question is not trying to get a comparison of the development of winglets/wingtips, with other aircraft components, as the question of [@Manu H](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8544/is-wingtip-design-mature/%22@Manu%20H%22) is.

[image]

Comment: @Federico, the questions do seem similar. However, they are addressing two different things.

Answer (score 7):

[Winglet design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/is-a-winglet-better-than-an-equal-span-extension) is driven more by [marketing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8544/is-wingtip-design-mature/8554#8554) than by [engineering](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/why-is-it-rare-for-small-aircraft-to-have-winglets/4986#4986), so every aircraft brand tries to cultivate their own, supposedly better, shape.

A study by [Nita and Scholz (PDF!), Chapter 6](http://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/OPerA/OPerA_PUB_DLRK_12-09-10.pdf) gives a good overview over recent winglet studies. A raked tip performs better, and if winglets could point downwards, they also could do better. As they are, they give only 28% to 38% drag reduction of an equivalent span increase.

[image: Raked wingtip of the Boeing 777-300]

Raked wingtip of the Boeing 777-300

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I take it the newer split winglets don't really include the benefits of a downward-pointing winglet, since they primarily point upwards?

Comment: @egid: A downward pointing winglet is only slightly better, and with the limited size cannot effect drag much. Theoretically, a variable-geometry winglet which can be folded up for landing would capture the benefit, but would work best when stopped halfway in the transition from pointing upward to pointing downward ;-)

Comment: @PeterKämpf Do you have link where you explain how raked wingtips works?Is raked wingtips better than simple horizontal extension?

Comment: @member2017 [Yes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/how-does-the-raked-wingtip-of-the-boeing-787-work/19078?r=SearchResults&s=1|80.4026#19078)