# What are the benefits of raked wingtips over tapered wingtips?

Tags: aerodynamics, winglets

[This post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/how-does-the-raked-wingtip-of-the-boeing-787-work) shows the differences between winglets and raked wingtips. I'm curious why raked wingtips have been developed when there are tapered wingtips. What are the benefits of raked wingtips over tapered wingtips?

Comment: Did you have a look also here? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14767/1467 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8544/1467

Comment: @Federico Thanks for the link. So should I conclude they are just different designs for different wings and have no meaningful difference?

Comment: That would be my take on it as well, yes, but if you feel you would like more clarifications on that, you can link in your question also the ones I linked to you and point out what you would like to have clarified.

Comment: There are quite a number of questions on this site about wingtips / winglets already, with very detailed answers. I feel they have already addressed your questions. If not, please feel free to clarify.